# Paste from clipboard into terminal with down-arrow, possible? :)

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, paste

I am quite new to Linux  and to Ubuntu - I have been using Ubuntu Gnome for 1 year.

Is it possible to make it so that when you are using the terminal and want to paste something in you just press the down-arrow to paste?

I know you can press up-arrow and get old commands and you need the down-arrow for going back to the start. But what I'm asking for is if it is possible to make it so when you press down you get the copied lines pasted from the clipboard.

EXAMPLE:
I have just run some commands and I want to paste a new command in so I just press the down-arrow.

EXAMPLE FOR WHEN IT WONT WORK:
I have just run some commands and I pressed up-key to find an old command, I went too far and pressed down-key to go back to the command I was looking for.

English is my second language and I have dyslexia, so I hope I got my idea across and you understood what I wanted to do.

Comment: The probably easiest way to copy-paste something is selecting the text and pasting it by clicking with the mousewheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paste something in the terminal, I am using Ctrl + Shift + V.
Copying goes same way: Ctrl + Shift + C

Just add the Shift key, since Ctrl + C is canceling a running operation in termminal.

Answer (score 2):

The two methods I use to insert text into the terminal from the clipboard:

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>
2. Right click mouse and select 'Paste'